# Custom Message for GCP Slack Build Notification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, slack, google-cloud-pubsub

I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configure-third-party-notifications#preparing_the_slack_application) tutorial to successfully setup GCP Slack build notification. Right now, I have the following Slack message:

```
// createSlackMessage creates a message from a build object.
const createSlackMessage = (build) => {
  const message = {
    text: `Build \`${build.id}\``,
    mrkdwn: true,
    attachments: [
      {
        title: 'Build logs',
        title_link: build.logUrl,
        fields: [{
          title: 'Status',
          value: build.status
        }]
      }
    ]
  };
  return message;
}
```

In addition to what's here, I also want to have information like project ID, the user who deployed it and other environment variables I am using during deployment (e.g. I use `_ENV` to distinguish dev server and production server). What is the way to extract such information? Where can I find the reference to the list of objects `build` object has? If `build` doesn't have my desired object by default, can I add that somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds), there you have all the options available that you can use.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

Not sure if you can add custom variables, but I think substitutions might be what you are looking for.

> Use substitutions in your build config file to substitute specific
>   variables at runtime. Substitutions are helpful for variables whose
>   value isn't known until build time, or to re-use an existing build
>   request with different variable values.
>
> Cloud Build provides built-in substitutions or you can define your own
>   substitutions. Use the substitutions field in your build's steps and
>   images fields to resolve their values at build time.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) you have more information about them.

Let me know.

Comment: This looks like what I've wanted! Do you know if I can add custom variables here?

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer, have a look, I think that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you customized the message that's sent to slack? I could not find that in the documentation (other than creating a notifier image myself based on [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-notifiers) repo)

Comment: Bro, have you managed to add a custom message?, can you let me know how to do that, I've just deployed the YAML file but I am confused about the documentation to customize the message.